# Generating Java source code using mixins from XML

Tags: java, xml, templates, mixins

I have a series of XML files describing varius entity types. I would like to transfrom these XML files into Java classes (source code, so I can check that they compile) using implementations based on mixins.

An example:

A XML file describing a villager:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<entity>
    <id>1</id>
    <gathers>
        <rate>12</rate>
    </gathers>
    <moves>
        <speed>4</speed>
    </moves>
</entity>
```

Should become the following class:

```
public class Villager implements Gathers, Moves {

    private final Gathers gathers;
    private final Moves moves;

    int getId() {

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSpeed() {

        return this.moves.getSpeed();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRate() {

        return this.gathers.getRate();
    }

    public Villager() {

        super();

        this.moves = new MovesMixin(4);
        this.gathers = new GathersMixin(12);
    }
}
```

I wish to do this in a way that is easily extended to cover new properties.

Are there existing packages / tools that can do something like this?

---

An updated example with templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/> 
<xsl:template match="entity">
/*
 * DO NOT MODIFY
 * This is an automatically generated class.  
 */
package xslt.entities;

import xslt.*;

public strictfp final class <xsl:value-of select="typeName"/> implements <xsl:apply-templates select="moves" mode="implement"/><xsl:apply-templates select="gathers" mode="implement"/><xsl:apply-templates select="shoots" mode="implement"/>Entity {
    <xsl:apply-templates select="moves" mode="mixin"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="gathers" mode="mixin"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="shoots" mode="mixin"/>
    public <xsl:value-of select="typeName"/>() {

        super();
    }
}
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="moves" mode="implement">Moves, </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="gathers" mode="implement">Gathers, </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="shoots" mode="implement">Shoots, </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="moves" mode="mixin">
    private final Moves moves = new MovesMixin(<xsl:value-of select="speed"/>);

    @Override
    public int getSpeed() {

        return this.moves.getSpeed();
    }
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="gathers" mode="mixin">
    private final Gathers gathers = new GathersMixin(<xsl:value-of select="rate"/>);

    @Override
    public int getRate() {

        return this.gathers.getRate();
    }
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="shoots" mode="mixin">
    private final Shoots shoots = new ShootsMixin(<xsl:value-of select="range"/>);

    @Override
    public int getRange() {

        return this.shoots.getRange();
    }
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots and lots of way to generate java from XML. My example here uses XSLT called from ANT.

## Example

```
├── build.xml
└── src
    ├── xml
    │   └── entity.xml
    └── xsl
        └── java.xsl
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="Generate Java" default="generate">

    <target name="generate">
        <xslt style="src/xsl/java.xsl" basedir="src/xml" destdir="build/java" extension=".java"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

### java.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                >

<xsl:output method="text"/> 

<!-- 
==============================
Match the root tag 
==============================
-->
<xsl:template match="entity">
public class Villager implements Gathers, Moves {

    private final Gathers gathers;
    private final Moves moves;

    int getId() {

        return <xsl:value-of select="id"/>;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSpeed() {

        return this.moves.getSpeed();
    }

    @Override
    public int getRate() {

        return this.gathers.getRate();
    }

    public Villager() {

        super();

        this.moves = new MovesMixin(<xsl:value-of select="moves/speed"/>);
        this.gathers = new GathersMixin(<xsl:value-of select="gathers/rate"/>);
    }
}
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Update

The following stylesheet enhancement demonstrates how source code generation can be made more dynamic dependent on the input XML.

Note:

- The generated Java contains a syntax error, apologies, it's almost complete.

### java.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                >

<xsl:output method="text"/> 

<!-- 
==============================
Match the root tag 
==============================
-->
<xsl:template match="entity">
public class Villager implements <xsl:apply-templates select="gathers|moves" mode="class-implements"/> {

    private final Gathers gathers;
    private final Moves moves;

    int getId() {

        return <xsl:value-of select="id"/>;
    }

    <xsl:apply-templates select="gathers|moves" mode="class-getters"/>

    public Villager() {

        super();

        <xsl:apply-templates select="gathers|moves" mode="mixins"/>
    }
}
</xsl:template>

<!-- 
==============================
Match the gather tag 
==============================
-->
<xsl:template match="gathers" mode="class-implements">
    <xsl:text>Gathers,</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="gathers" mode="class-getters">
    @Override
    public int getRate() {

        return this.gathers.getRate();
    }
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="gathers" mode="mixins">
        this.gathers = new GathersMixin(<xsl:value-of select="rate"/>);
</xsl:template>

<!-- 
==============================
Match the gather tag 
==============================
-->
<xsl:template match="moves" mode="class-implements">
    <xsl:text>Moves,</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="moves" mode="class-getters">
    @Override
    public int getSpeed() {

        return this.moves.getSpeed();
    }
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="moves" mode="mixins">
        this.moves = new MovesMixin(<xsl:value-of select="speed"/>);
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This solution works well and is easily integrated into Eclipse. One concern I have though is that some XML files will require different mixins (e.g. "Archer" might require "Shoots" and "Moves", but not "Gather"). Is there a way to reduce the complexity that this would create in the xsl?

Comment: @user1256041 Should be possible by creating an XSLT template match for each object type.

Comment: Added to op, for anyone who is interested.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AspectJ's Inter-type Declarations, which basically allows you to add new members (fields, methods, constructors) defined in an aspect to an existing type.

http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/language-interType.html

It's not something that would understand your XML descriptors, but certainly a way to implement mixins in java, so maybe you can make use of it.